# Rust why compiler infers a different type beyond our expection

Tags: rust

I have such a piece of code:

```rust
struct Node {
    value: u32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
fn traverse(last_nodes: &mut VecDeque<&Node>, result: &mut Vec<u32>) {
    if last_nodes.len() == 0 {
        return;
    }
    let mut childrens = VecDeque::new();
    while let Some(node) = last_nodes.pop_front() {
        result.push(node.value);
        if let Some(n) = &node.left {
            childrens.push_back(&*n);
        }
        if let Some(n) = &node.right {
            childrens.push_back(&*n);
        }
    }
    traverse(&mut childrens, result)
}
```

pay more attention to below code, I want `childrens` to be a VecDeque<&Node> type

```rust
let mut childrens = VecDeque::new();
```

however, it gets a result like `VecDeque<&Box<Node>>` because of below code and inference of compiler

```rust
childrens.push_back(&*n);
```

but if we correct the above code to be more definate, we can get our codes passing the compiler

```rust
let mut childrens:VecDeque<&Node> = VecDeque::new();
```

I don't know if it is the imperfection of compiler

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is correct. The type of `&node.left` and `&node.right` is `&Option<Box<Node>>`. As such, matching it against `Some(n)` makes `n` has type `&Box<Node>`, by [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html). So `&*n` is also `&Box<Node>`, and you're creating a `VecDeque<&Box<Node>>`.

However, `&Box<Node>` can be coerced to `&Node` via deref coercion. So, if the compiler *knows* the type of the `VecDeque` is `VecDeque<&Node>`, and so it expects `push_back()` to take `&Node`, it will coerce `&Box<Node>` to that and everything will work perfectly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it‘s really helpful.You are right I have correct my question and I realized that I lacked the knowledge of `coercion`